# Error while saving OrderAttributes values in BroadLeaf table blc_order_attribute

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I created the OrderAttribute object and set its values and send it to the Dao to exxecute EntityManager.merge() function. It compiles very well but doenst update the entry in the database. The object value gets its value. No doubt. Any solution?

OrderAttributeService:
@Service("orderAttributeService")
public class OrderAttributeServiceImpl implements OrderAttributeService {

```
@Resource(name = "orderAttributeDao")
protected OrderAttributeDao orderAttributeDao;

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OrderConfirmationServiceImpl.class);

@Override
public void saveOrderAttributes(OrderConfirmation orderConfirmation, Order order) {
    OrderAttribute orderAttribute = new OrderAttributeImpl();
    orderAttribute.setOrder(order); //order object
    orderAttribute.setName("deviceId"); //string
    orderAttribute.setValue(orderConfirmation.getDeviceId()); //string

    orderAttributeDao.save(orderAttribute);
}
```

OrderAttributeDao:
@Repository("orderAttributeDao")
public class OrderAttributeDaoImpl implements OrderAttributeDao {

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "blPU")
protected EntityManager em;

@Override
@Transactional("blTransactionManager")
public void save(final OrderAttribute orderAttribute) {
//   em.joinTransaction();
     em.merge(orderAttribute);
//   em.flush();
}
```

}

Comment: Oh, I wonder what the JPA providers LOG says ...

Comment: Nothing as such. No exception. Just not getting inserted into database

Comment: Oh. I'm sure it will say something. Like is a transaction active, like the state of the objects, etc etc

Comment: When I use em.flush() after em.merge(), It says "Transaction is not in progress!"